# How do I convert HTML document made in JSoup?

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

I have some HTML code and want to convert for JSoup, but my code did not work.

My code is:

```
<div id="right_song">
    <div class="mp3_title"><b>Title</b></div>
    <div class="empty"></div>
    <div class="empty"></div>
</div>

<div class='songInfoMobile' style='font-size:11px; margin-top:5px;'>
            3.71 mb            
</div>

<div class="mp3_bottom_box">
    <div class="button_box">
        <div class="download_button">
            <a href="http://www.mytest.com/test.html" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Download</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JSoup code is :

```
link = rightSong.child(2).select("a[href]").first().attr("href");
```

I  want to add from `div id="right_song"` to  `http://www.mytest.com/test.html` in my JSoup code. What's wrong?

Comment: So, you want to replace a `href` attribute of a selected tag with the given link ? Or create a new link and add it below the given tag ? Maybe you can add more code to show what you have tried. (fe how you have selected the element with the song - to be sure that it's done correctly)

Comment: Hello KarelG, Please check again. I have updated my correct problem. Thanks Suresh

Comment: In the above code, the `<a>` element belongs to the second *sibling*, not *child* of `<div id=right_song">`. Besides the code seems to miss an ending `</div>`.

Comment: @xaver-kapeller How can you be sure the edit reflects what the OP got instead of some mistyping?

Comment: @Nasha All I did was correct formatting and add missing closing tags for the `div`s. Malformed HTML is helping no one. And if the OP can't manage or can't be bothered to to post valid and correctly formatted HTML then I won't hesitate to correct that. You shouldn't hesitate either. Any mistakes that comes from this is not the fault of the person making the edit, but instead the fault of the OP posting malformed HTML in the first place.

Comment: @xavier-kapeller I was reluctant to fix the improper HTML instead wanted to make sure the OP would take it into account. Mistakes are common. After all no proper format, no response, right? ;-)

Comment: Hello Nasha, I have solved my problem. The solution is                                                  link = rightSong.siblingElements().select("a[href]").first().attr("href"); Thanks to all friends

Answer (score 0):

Solution found by OP:

> Hello Nasha, I have solved my problem. The solution is link = rightSong.siblingElements().select("a[href]").first().attr("href"); Thanks to all friends